# Making 3D scan model using Intel RealSense D435 Point clouds

Tags: realsense

Earlier this week I received the Intel RealSense D435 camera and now I am discovering its capabilities. After doing a few hours of research, I discovered the previous version of the SDK had a 3D model scan example application. Since SDK 2.0, this example application is no longer present making it harder to create 3D models with the camera.

I have managed to create various Point cloud (.ply) files with the camera, and now I try to use CloudCompare to generate a 3D model of it. However, without any success. Since my knowledge about computer vision is rather basic, I reach out to the community how it's possible to accomplish a 3D model scan using only PointClouds. The model can be rough, but preferable most noisy data needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try recfusion 1.7.3 for scanning. 99 euro

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Recfusion looks neat and should do the trick. However, I rather wish to develop my own application and am therefore requesting some basic knowledge in how to accomplish this using only point clouds.